# Checkbox not aligning despite CSS code applied

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my checkboxes and labels aligned (into two a column), but it isn't working. Any idea what I can do to get it fixed?

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wfju61oq/1/

```
.option label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
.option input {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is it about the checkbox for 'Refill Jugs' appearing on a newline?

Comment: If it is about Refill, you have an extra </label> closing tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.option label {
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
}
.option input {
  float:right;
}
```

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wfju61oq/7/).

Comment: Refill Jugs checkbox is way off :D

Comment: don't use the OP's original fiddle but rather Muleskinner's, the OP left an extra `</label>` after `Refill Jugs`...

Answer (score 0):

```
    label {
        display: block;
        width: 300px;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Here is a working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wfju61oq/8/

Warning: you have a `&`character in one of your id: this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wfju61oq/10/

remove `margin:0` for `label` and `position:relative; top:-1px;`

added `border` for better view of `vertical alignment`

```css
.option label {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.option input {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  *overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Which Service Do You Require?</legend>
    <label for="Hostess">Hostess
      <input type="checkbox" id="Hostess" value="Hostess" />
    </label>
    <label for="usher">Usher
      <input type="checkbox" id="usher" value="usher" />
    </label>
    <label for="welcomeguests">Welcome Guests
      <input type="checkbox" id="welcomeguests" value="welcomeguests" />
    </label>
    <label for="guestlists">Guest Lists
      <input type="checkbox" id="guestlists" value="guestlists" />
    </label>
    <label for="seatguests">Seat Guests
      <input type="checkbox" id="seatguests" value="seatguests" />
    </label>
    <label for="servebuffmeal">Serve Buffet Meal
      <input type="checkbox" id="servebuffmeal" value="servebuffmeal" />
    </label>
    <label for="servesitmeal">Serve Sit-Down Meal
      <input type="checkbox" id="servesitmeal" value="servesitmeal" />
    </label>
    <label for="clearplates">Clear Plates
      <input type="checkbox" id="clearplates" value="clearplates" />
    </label>
    <label for="cleartables">Clear Tables
      <input type="checkbox" id="cleartables" value="cleartables" />
    </label>
    <label for="returnhplates">Return Hired Plates
      <input type="checkbox" id="returnhplates" value="returnhplates" />
    </label>
    <label for="refilljuggs">Refill Jugs
      <input type="checkbox" id="refilljugs" value="refilljuggs" />
    </label>
    <label for="">Serve V.I.P Guests
      <input type="checkbox" id="servevipguests" value="servevipguests" />
    </label>
    <label for="">Cross-Check Invite List
      <input type="checkbox" id="crosscheckivlist" value="crosscheckivlist" />
    </label>
    <label for="">Meet & Greet Guests
      <input type="checkbox" id="Meet&GreetGuests" value="Meet&GreetGuests" />
    </label>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <label>Other
      <input id="other" name="other" type="text" placeholder="Other" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```